# "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: " during pip install -r requirements.txt

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

Getting some weird error that states that "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: " All I did was pip install -r requirements.txt. I've tried downloading and installing all dependencies individually and were successfully installed but in here it shows error.

```
tensorflow>=1.15.2
keras==2.3.1
imutils==0.5.3
numpy==1.18.2
opencv-python==4.2.0.*
matplotlib==3.2.1
scipy==1.4.1
```

Above is my requirements.txt file.
Error output is shown below.

```
Collecting tensorflow>=1.15.2
  Using cached tensorflow-2.7.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (430.8 MB)
Collecting keras==2.3.1
  Using cached Keras-2.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (377 kB)
Collecting imutils==0.5.3
  Using cached imutils-0.5.3.tar.gz (17 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting numpy==1.18.2
  Using cached numpy-1.18.2.zip (5.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'D:\Projects\Python\Face-Mask-Detection\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'D:\Projects\Python\Face-Mask-Detection\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\grvra\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpblo49wyv'
       cwd: C:\Users\grvra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm4x42y9\numpy_0939fd38ac9946b9b25c934585e198b7
  Complete output (72 lines):
  Running from numpy source directory.
  setup.py:461: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
    run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
  Cythonizing sources
  Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
  Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
  C:\Users\grvra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm4x42y9\numpy_0939fd38ac9946b9b25c934585e198b7\tools\cythonize.py:75: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
    required_version = LooseVersion('0.29.14')
  C:\Users\grvra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm4x42y9\numpy_0939fd38ac9946b9b25c934585e198b7\tools\cythonize.py:77: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
    if LooseVersion(cython_version) < required_version:
  Processing numpy/random\_bit_generator.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
  Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
  Could not locate executable g77
  Could not locate executable f77
  Could not locate executable ifort
  Could not locate executable ifl
  Could not locate executable f90
  Could not locate executable DF
  Could not locate executable efl
  Could not locate executable gfortran
  Could not locate executable f95
  Could not locate executable g95
  Could not locate executable efort
  Could not locate executable efc
  Could not locate executable flang
  don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
  C:\Users\grvra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm4x42y9\numpy_0939fd38ac9946b9b25c934585e198b7\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
      Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
      Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
      A better performance should be easily gained by switching
      Blas library.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
  C:\Users\grvra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm4x42y9\numpy_0939fd38ac9946b9b25c934585e198b7\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
      the BLAS environment variable.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
  C:\Users\grvra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm4x42y9\numpy_0939fd38ac9946b9b25c934585e198b7\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
      the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
  C:\Users\grvra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm4x42y9\numpy_0939fd38ac9946b9b25c934585e198b7\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
  C:\Users\grvra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm4x42y9\numpy_0939fd38ac9946b9b25c934585e198b7\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
  C:\Users\grvra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lk0zd224\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
  running dist_info
  running build_src
  creating build
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\distutils
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/1e/ff467ac56bfeaea51d4a2e72d315c1fe440b20192fea7e460f0f248acac8/numpy-1.18.2.zip#sha256=e7894793e6e8540dbeac77c87b489e331947813511108ae097f1715c018b8f3d (from https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'D:\Projects\Python\Face-Mask-Detection\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'D:\Projects\Python\Face-Mask-Detection\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\grvra\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpblo49wyv' Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.18.2 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0rc1, 1.16.0rc2, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.17.0rc1, 1.17.0rc2, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.18.0rc1, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, 1.18.4, 1.18.5, 1.19.0rc1, 1.19.0rc2, 1.19.0, 1.19.1, 1.19.2, 1.19.3, 1.19.4, 1.19.5, 1.20.0rc1, 1.20.0rc2, 1.20.0, 1.20.1, 1.20.2, 1.20.3, 1.21.0rc1, 1.21.0rc2, 1.21.0, 1.21.1, 1.21.2, 1.21.3, 1.21.4, 1.21.5, 1.22.0rc1, 1.22.0rc2, 1.22.0rc3, 1.22.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.18.2
```

Comment: It does say "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required" near the end - do you have this installed (there's a link in the error if you don't)  and on your path?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the numpy version you are forcing pip to install (numpy==1.18.2) remove the version (just put numpy) and try again `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

The key is found at the end of the output

```
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/1e/ff467ac56bfeaea51d4a2e72d315c1fe440b20192fea7e460f0f248acac8/numpy-1.18.2.zip#sha256=e7894793e6e8540dbeac77c87b489e331947813511108ae097f1715c018b8f3d (from https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'D:\Projects\Python\Face-Mask-Detection\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'D:\Projects\Python\Face-Mask-Detection\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\grvra\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpblo49wyv' Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.18.2 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0rc1, 1.16.0rc2, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.17.0rc1, 1.17.0rc2, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.18.0rc1, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, 1.18.4, 1.18.5, 1.19.0rc1, 1.19.0rc2, 1.19.0, 1.19.1, 1.19.2, 1.19.3, 1.19.4, 1.19.5, 1.20.0rc1, 1.20.0rc2, 1.20.0, 1.20.1, 1.20.2, 1.20.3, 1.21.0rc1, 1.21.0rc2, 1.21.0, 1.21.1, 1.21.2, 1.21.3, 1.21.4, 1.21.5, 1.22.0rc1, 1.22.0rc2, 1.22.0rc3, 1.22.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.18.2
```

Apparently your Microsoft Visual C++ needs to updated. If there's no reason to use a specific `numpy` version, simply remove the `==1.18.2` from the requirements file.